# google drive api java update content of a file

Tags: java, api, google-drive-api, insert-update, drive

I'm getting illegal argument exception while using update mediaContent.

```
private static File updateFile(Drive service, String fileId, 
         String newMimeType, String newFilename, boolean newRevision) {
      try {
        // First retrieve the file from the API.
        File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();


        file.setMimeType(newMimeType);

        // File's new content.
        java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(newFilename);
        FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(newMimeType, fileContent);

        // Send the request to the API.
        File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute();

        return updatedFile;
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        return null;
      }
    }
```

I'm getting this exception:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setInitiationRequestMethod(MediaHttpUploader.java:872)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.initializeMediaUpload(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:237)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Update.<init>(Drive.java:3163)
at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files.update(Drive.java:3113)
at sai.sai.vasa.main(vasa.java:247)
```

when I am updating only metadata of a file the method is update(fileId,fileMetadata), it is working fine. but when I tried to add mediacontent as third parameter in update as defined in api I am getting the above exception.

How to solve this error?
How to do it in version3. I want to do it in version3 only but I couldn't find the update code in drive API.

Answer (score 0):

From the Google Drive Rest API documentation [sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update#examples), update is executed like below

`File updatedFile = service.files().update(fileId, file, mediaContent).execute()`;

Where `mediaContent` is of `FileContent` class.

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with typecasting it to `AbstractInputStreamContent` but there's no need to typecast it as such due to `FileContent` class is already a subclass of `AbstractInputStreamContent`.

You can check that out over [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/FileContent)

Comment: Thank you for the response.
Edited the code in question. We tried what you said 
but still the same error. Please can you check where we did mistake again.